# How to edit eval.lua script in NeuralTalk2 to process a single image?

Tags: lua, torch

I want to modify the script eval.lua provided in NeuralTalk2 code.
The script works with a given images' path.
I wish edit it in order to call this script giving just a single image path instead of the path of a directory containing several images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could at least provide a link to that file so we don't have too search for it...
your question is like: hey guys, I'm too lazy to search the script for the words path, folder or image. can you please do that for me?

Comment: @Piglet thanks for your reply!
The link to NeuralTalk2 is [link](https://github.com/karpathy/neuraltalk2)  and the script is "eval.lua".
I have tried to modify the input of this script without success.

Comment: then update your question. tell us what you tried, what you think should work...